# ListView проблема с кликом item'ов

Tags: android, listview

Здравствуйте, не могу понять в чём дело. Во фрагменте есть `listview`, объявил, инициализировал. Далее в адаптере, в методе `getView()` повешал слушатель `listview.onItemClickListener...` но при запуске программы не идут клики по айтемам ListView. Т.е. даже контекстное меню не вызывается. Перепробовал многие методы порекомендовавшие от гугла, но всё без успеха. В моём проекте есть активити с похожей задачей, есть листвью и клики по нему идут без всяких там доподнений в xml и т.п. По сути для меня это обычная практика, раньше такого не наблюдалось, а вот тут прям не хочет кликать и всё...( Я временно собрал кастыль на основе интерфейса, слушатель клика прикрутил к основному LinearLayout'у. По сути то что надо, но...я вот думаю вдруг мне в будущем понадобится и контекстное меню, да и в общем хочется понять саму проблему. В разметке удалял всё "временно лишнее" думал может     элементы разметки как то перебивают слушатель, но нет. И `clickable(false)` устанавливал для всех тех элементов с которых мне не нужно ничего слушать. Не помогает. Вот говорю, есть идентичная ситуация с активити в которой всё работает, да и раньше делал всё так как учили, но сейчас ничего не помогает) Помогите пожалуйста.

Фрагмент

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_ads, container, false);
    final OnItemIdSelected listener = (OnItemIdSelected) getActivity();

    getActivity().setTitle(listener.item_title());
    adslist = view.findViewById(R.id.adsListView);

    adsLoad = new AdsLoad(this, listener.item_id());
    adsLoad.execute();
/*
    adslist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            / Нет вызова /
        }
    });
*/
    FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AdsAddLayout.class);
            intent.putExtra("categories", String.valueOf(listener.item_id()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Adapter

```
public class AdapterViewAds extends ArrayAdapter<ResponseAdsArray> {

private Context context;
private ListView adslist;
private OnItemClickAds callback;
private ArrayList<ResponseAdsArray> data;

private String LOG_TAG = "AdapterViewAds";

public interface OnItemClickAds {
    void onItemAdsSelected(int ads_id);
}

public AdapterViewAds(Context context, ArrayList<ResponseAdsArray> values, ListView adslist, OnItemClickAds callback) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_view_ads, values);

    this.data = values;
    this.context = context;
    this.adslist = adslist;
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, null);

    LinearLayout adsLinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.adsLinearLayout);

    TextView header = view.findViewById(R.id.header);
    TextView text   = view.findViewById(R.id.text);

    final int ads_id    = data.get(position).getAdsId();
    String adsText      = data.get(position).getAdsText();
    String adsHeader    = data.get(position).getAdsName();
    final ArrayList imgFiles  = data.get(position).getAdsFiles();


    adslist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            /* Нет вызова */
        }
    });

/*  Тут костыль
    adsLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            callback.onItemAdsSelected(ads_id);
        }
    });
*/
    header.setText(adsHeader);
    text.setText(adsText);


    return view;
}
```

Listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/adsListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/colorDivider"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="#069"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Разметка

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/adsLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:onClick="onItemClick"
android:clickable="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeCreatedView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="00:00" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "в методе getView() повешал слушатель listview.onItemClickListener" - переместите этот слушатель в ваш фрагмент/активити и все заработает. В адаптере же вы можете навесить клики на конкретные вьюшки.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид пробовал. Так тоже не работает да и много где говорят что всё же слушатель вешать рекомендуется в самом адаптере

Comment: Создал листвью сейчас в нём один элемент - текствью. Переношу слушатель в сам фрагмент, не работает, в адаптере, не работает. В разметку дописывал кучу всяких кастылей. Игрался и с фокусэйблами и с кликэйблами

Comment: прикрепите код фрагмента, адаптера и разметки.

Comment: @Андроид Андроид, я обновил свой вопрос

Comment: Есть у кого идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогло только это

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```